# It's me who do it or it's me who does it?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I just want to check which one native speakers say (more often)
"It's me who **do** it" or "It's me who **does** it"?

xpda said: ""It is me," is more common, and correct. However, "It is I who am here," is also correct, and "who am here" can be left off and implied, making "It is I," also correct." at this link: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/which-one-is-correct-to-say-its-me-or-its-i

Comment: I don't say the first one.

Comment: What exactly is it you are asking about: "it's me/I who is/am..." or "it's me/I **who do/does it**"? I guess, the latter since the former has been answered in the post you provide the link to. Am I right?